# Symmetric zooming of image within scrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pinchzoom, scroll-paging

I am new to iPhone to iOS development. and I want a demo for zoom in and zoom out (symmetric zooming of image) a image within a scrollview in iOS.This is my code : in this code i have taken an image view within a scrollview(ZoomScrollView) and scrollview within a another Scrollview(scrollView_Gallery).Thanks in advance..

//ZoomGalleryViewController.m//

```
    scrollView_Gallery.backgroundColor                 = [UIColor yellowColor];
    scrollView_Gallery.delegate                        = self;
    scrollView_Gallery.pagingEnabled                   = YES;
    scrollView_Gallery.userInteractionEnabled          = YES;
    scrollView_Gallery.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator  = NO;
    scrollView_Gallery.showsVerticalScrollIndicator    = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView_Gallery];

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [scrollView_Gallery setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*[arrayUrl count],self.view.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        [scrollView_Gallery setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width*[arrayUrl count],[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayUrl count]; i++)
    {
        zoomScrollView                       = [[ZoomScrollView alloc]init];
        zoomScrollView.backgroundColor       = [UIColor redColor];
        [zoomScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(zoomScrollView.contentSize.width,zoomScrollView.frame.size.height)];

        CGRect frame                         = scrollView_Gallery.frame;
        frame.origin.x                       = (frame.size.width)* i;
        frame.origin.y                       = 0;
        zoomScrollView.frame                 = frame;
        zoomScrollView.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        NSMutableURLRequest *request         = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[arrayUrl objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"photopath"]]];
        __weak UIImageView *weakImageView    = zoomScrollView.imageView;

        zoomScrollView.imageView.tag         = i;
        zoomScrollView.ZOOM_VIEW_TAG         = zoomScrollView.imageView.tag;
        [zoomScrollView.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                                        placeholderImage:nil
                                                 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
        {
            NSLog(@"image=%f,imageheight=%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);
            UIImageView *strongImageView = weakImageView; // make local strong reference to protect against race conditions

            strongImageView.frame  = CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width*image.scale, image.size.height*image.scale);
            strongImageView.center = scrollView_Gallery.center;

            NSLog(@"image11    = %f, imageheight11 = %f",image.size.width*image.scale, image.size.height*image.scale);
            NSLog(@"imageScale = %f",image.scale);

            if (!strongImageView) return;
            [UIView transitionWithView:strongImageView
                              duration:0.3
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                                strongImageView.image = image;
         }
            completion:NULL];
           //[scrollView_Gallery setContentOffset:CGPointMake(strongImageView.frame.size.width * (indexNumber+1), 0)];
        }failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@", error);
        }];
        [scrollView_Gallery addSubview:zoomScrollView];

        [zoomScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(zoomScrollView.contentSize.width,zoomScrollView.frame.size.height)];
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
             [scrollView_Gallery setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width * (indexNumber), 0)];
        }
        else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
              [scrollView_Gallery setContentOffset:CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * (indexNumber), 0)];

        }


//  ZoomScrollView.h//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MRZoomScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;


@end
```

//    MRZoomScrollView.m//

```
#import "MRZoomScrollView.h"

#define MRScreenWidth      CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame)
#define MRScreenHeight     CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame)

@interface MRZoomScrollView (Utility)

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;

@end

@implementation MRZoomScrollView

@synthesize imageView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.delegate = self;
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, MRScreenWidth, MRScreenHeight);

        [self initImageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initImageView
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    // The imageView can be zoomed largest size

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, MRScreenWidth * 2.5, MRScreenHeight * 2.5);
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    // Add gesture,double tap zoom imageView.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    [doubleTapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];
    [doubleTapGesture release];

    float minimumScale = self.frame.size.width / imageView.frame.size.width;
    [self setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [self setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}


#pragma mark - Zoom methods

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    float newScale = self.zoomScale * 1.5;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gesture locationInView:gesture.view]];
    [self zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center
{
    CGRect zoomRect;
    zoomRect.size.height = self.frame.size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = self.frame.size.width  / scale;
    zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);
    return zoomRect;
}


#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) tutorial, it was helpful for me:

Comment: With the help of this tutorial,I am able to pinch and zoom an image within a scroll view symetrically  but I have to work on symmetric zoom and pinch in scrollview paging. while doing paging like zooming I'm facing the problem in symmetric zooming of images. I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: In the above, i mean to say that I'm trying to use a scroll view to have pagination with pages of subviews that are images that can be pinched zoomed on iOS symmetrically.

Comment: i think that better is use UICollectionView with enabled paging, put UIScrollView to its Cells, and put UIImages to its.

Comment: i have a demo in which zooming and pinching of image is done with paging. but when I'm using this code to my code then zooming is not symmetric.this is the link of demo:http://code4app.net/ios/Pinch-ScrollView-Image/516654e76803fa131b000000.

Comment: So, I try to use this code, and it works fine, it symetricaly zommed, are you sure, that you doing all like in this example?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the my code for Symmetric zooming but I'm not able to get the what is the actual problem.? I'm not able to get the symmetrical zooming. Please tell me what I have done wrong??

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using **UIScrollView** and enable `enabledZoom` ON.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

in viewDidLoad method paste this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280, 960);
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;
}
```

Comment: I have used this code but still facing the problem. I want to make a photo gallery with image zooming on double tap and pinch zoom with paging. Can you provide me a demo project for that? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: I'm trying to use a scroll view to have pagination with pages of subviews that are images that can be pinched zoomed on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a property scrollView, try the following code in your view controller s viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods:

```
  self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=2.0;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=self.scrollView.frame.size;
    self.scrollView.bounces=YES;
    self.scrollView.delegate=self;
```

Let your view controller conform to the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. And implement the delegate method :

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;// return the imageView inside the scrollview which has to be scaled.
}
```

Comment: I have used this code but still facing the problem. can you provide me a demo project